# How to use 3 select box in a single row with bootsrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form similar to this.
3 input field on a row without using labels on the left side.
Actually i want to use the labels on the right side.

I couldnt use normal `<label></label>`tags to get the label on teh right side. didnt worked.

My solution was using span with input inline.

[image]

I have tried to do that with form groups. But result wanst so good. Maybe you can help me.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Aktivite Süresi</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                </select>
                <span class="inline-help">gün</span>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                </select>
                <span class="inline-help">saat</span>


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">

                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                </select>
                <span class="inline-help">dakika</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the result comes up
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can add class="col-md-4" instead of col-md-3

provided you can increase the parent class from col-md-4 to col-md-8 if inner child still does not work.

Total should be 12. So you can extend value upto col-md-12 max.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solution for this

Solution 1:
[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Son rezervasyon zamanı 1</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <div class="form-group row">

                                                    <div class="col-md-4">

                                                        <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                            <option>0</option>
                                                            <option>1</option>
                                                            <option>2</option>
                                                            <option>3</option>
                                                            <option>4</option>
                                                            <option>5</option>
                                                            <option>6</option>
                                                            <option>7</option>
                                                            <option>8</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <span class="inline-help">gün</span>

                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class="col-md-4">

                                                        <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                            <option>0</option>
                                                            <option>1</option>
                                                            <option>2</option>
                                                            <option>3</option>
                                                            <option>4</option>
                                                            <option>5</option>
                                                            <option>6</option>
                                                            <option>7</option>
                                                            <option>8</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <span class="inline-help">saat</span>


                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class="col-md-4">

                                                        <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                            <option>0</option>
                                                            <option>1</option>
                                                            <option>2</option>
                                                            <option>3</option>
                                                            <option>4</option>
                                                            <option>5</option>
                                                            <option>6</option>
                                                            <option>7</option>
                                                            <option>8</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <span class="inline-help">dakika</span>

                                                    </div>





                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Solution 2:

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Son rezervasyon zamanı 2</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                    <option>0</option>
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                    <option>6</option>
                                                    <option>7</option>
                                                    <option>8</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="inline-help">gün</span>

                                                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                    <option>0</option>
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                    <option>6</option>
                                                    <option>7</option>
                                                    <option>8</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="inline-help">saat</span>

                                                <select class="form-control input-xsmall input-inline">
                                                    <option>0</option>
                                                    <option>1</option>
                                                    <option>2</option>
                                                    <option>3</option>
                                                    <option>4</option>
                                                    <option>5</option>
                                                    <option>6</option>
                                                    <option>7</option>
                                                    <option>8</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="inline-help">dakika</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```